# Which format my webcam produces

Tags: video, ffmpeg, camera, codec

How can i find out which format (preffix) my USB webcam produces ? I want recording webcam to HDD with ffmpeg and i need save the capture record without reencoding because of CPU usage (i using raspberry PI and pi's hardware is not suitable for this). And the problem is when i executed this command :

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y /home/pi/camera_records/room/test
```

i got a output error :

```
[NULL @ 0x1719d90] Unable to find a suitable output format for '/home/pi/camera_records/room/test'
/home/pi/camera_records/room/test: Invalid argument
```

and i think i must specify the output preffix (the output preffix must be like webcam format because i do not use reencoding) but i do not know what format is input ... (mp4,h264,... ???) **How find out the webcam format? I use official Raspbian system.**